# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, sql, apache, xampp

i updated windows then xampp broken , i dont know why.i done all the things that i read in this forum but dont works , changed the ports , eliminated the ibdata and nothing...,i dont know what to do.

201

```
5-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 18:14:29 1f30 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 18:14:29 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 18:14:30 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1665234
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-23 18:14:33 5304 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 18:30:43 1554 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 18:30:43 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665244 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-03-23 18:30:44 4928 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-03-23 18:30:46 4928 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-23 18:30:46 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 18:30:46 4928 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1665244
2015-03-23 18:30:46 4928 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-23 18:30:46 4928 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-23 18:30:46 4928 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-23 18:30:47 4928 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-23 18:30:47 4928 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-23 18:30:47 4928 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.21'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 18:50:30 19cc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] InnoDB: C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Binlog end
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Binlog end
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-03-23 18:57:09 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1665254
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-03-23 18:57:10 4928 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 18:57:17 968 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 18:57:17 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 18:57:18 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1665254
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-23 18:57:19 4912 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-23 18:57:20 4912 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-23 18:57:20 4912 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.21'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 22:39:48 14c8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 22:39:48 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 22:39:49 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-23 22:39:49 6500 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665254 and 1665254 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2301139 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-03-23 22:39:49 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-03-23 22:39:49 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-03-23 22:39:49 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-03-23 22:39:51 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-03-23 22:39:51 6500 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-03-23 22:39:53 6500 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-23 22:39:53 6500 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:39:53 6500 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 2301139
2015-03-23 22:39:54 6500 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-23 22:39:54 6500 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-23 22:39:54 6500 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-23 22:39:54 6500 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 22:48:29 1d7c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665254 and 1665254 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2301149 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-03-23 22:48:29 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-03-23 22:48:30 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-03-23 22:48:30 6300 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 2301149
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-23 22:48:33 6300 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-23 22:48:34 6300 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-23 22:48:34 6300 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.21'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-23 22:52:57 ec InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-23 22:52:57 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665254 and 1665254 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2301159 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-03-23 22:52:58 8036 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 2301159
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-23 22:53:01 8036 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-24 16:02:04 7340 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-24 16:02:04 568 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-24 16:02:05 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 2434658
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-24 16:02:11 7340 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-24 16:02:12 7340 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-24 16:02:12 7340 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.21'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-26 17:32:35 176c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-26 17:32:35 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-26 17:32:36 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-26 17:32:36 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-26 17:32:36 6944 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2434658 and 2434658 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3122958 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-03-26 17:32:36 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-03-26 17:32:36 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-03-26 17:32:36 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-03-26 17:32:37 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-03-26 17:32:37 6944 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 3122958
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-26 17:32:40 6944 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-26 17:32:48 6944 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-26 17:32:48 6944 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] InnoDB: C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-03-23 18:50:30 6520 [ERROR] Aborting
```

check your ibdata1 file and C:\xampp\mysql\data folder permission